# RAM allocation in WHM/Cpanel using SSH

Tags: mysql, ssh, cpanel, vps, whm

I have a server(VPS) with 4gb ram. I would like to create 4 cpanels with allowed RAM as 1gb each, so that they use their individual memory. How can i do so using ssh?

Comment: You have mentioned you would like to create 4 cPanels.. does it mean 4 users?

Comment: Please move your question to [su] or [sf]. It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: ya. it means 4 users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to setup memory limit for your user then you need to use CloudLinux OS on your server, With the CloudLinux server you can set memory, process and cpu limit on account basis

https://www.cloudlinux.com/about/features.php

Comment: I have linux server with CentOS. Is it possible in it?

Comment: No, You can not setup memory limit for your cpanel user's process with the CentOS.